# Ordering mysql rows from derived columns

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I wanted to retrieve rows from the mysql database and order them by votes:

```
votes_up + votes_down = votes
```

table:

```
posts{id, post_text, votes_up, votes_down, date}
ORDER BY votes
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT id, post_text, votes_up, votes_down, date, sum(votes_up + votes_down) as 'Votes'
FROM posts
ORDER BY sum(votes_up + votes_down)
```

Comment: thanks for the great answer ;), can i aslo ask you to access the votes_up or votes_down values, deos that automatically come this query

Comment: Add the other columns you need to the select statement, I'll update my answer

Answer (score 3):

Traditional SQL allows you to use column aliases in the ORDER BY:

```
  SELECT p.votes_up + p.votes_down AS total_votes
    FROM POSTS p
ORDER BY total_votes
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `blablabla ORDER BY sum(votes_up + votes_down)`, but be careful and don't use this on high-loaded production databases, because sum() will be calculeted "on the fly" and it will be very slow for large tables!

Comment: im just doing it on the posts made in the last 3 hours, so it wont perform on all the rows in the post tbale, would that still be alright

Comment: is thier alternative to doing this, the most important thing is that i order the rows on total votes